# Date format for oData.create

Tags: sapui5

I have a create with filter oEntry:

```
oEntry.Budat = new Date();

oDataModel.create('/DeliveryCompleteSet', oEntry, null, function(oData){
                 MessageToast.show(oData.Text,{
                        duration: 5000,
                        width: "100em",
                    });
```

oEntry contains one date field and it gives me an error "invalid date" when I execute the create. What format does the field have to be?

Comment: How did you apply the edm.dateTime format to your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [here](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/overview/)

> **Edm.DateTime**  Represents date and time with values ranging from 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 1753 A.D. through 11:59:59 P.M, December
>   9999 A.D.